# Is it possible to play FS15 mulitplyer via offline Wired LAN?

Tags: farming-simulator-2015

As the question suggests.

Is it possible to LAN FS15 with a hard connection between two computers? Or can you only play LAN online?

Thanks Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive research, I can safely conclude that FS15 does not support offline multiplayer, and does require an online connection to play. This also means that you need two copies of the game to play online, even if you do have the disc version of the game.